# Why didn't the surface of Vulcan have massive gravity due to the red matter?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-2009, vulcan

I was watching the Star Trek reboot again last night, and the scene where the red matter was injected into the centre of Vulcan got me thinking.

Clearly this was having major catastrophic effects as it was pulling the whole planet Vulcan towards it.  However, while rocks were falling (and the odd statue), and cracks forming in the crust, the gravity for those on the surface seemed unaffected.

Given that a singularity had been placed at the centre of Vulcan, and the extreme gravity that it would entail (it *did* suck the whole planet in), why weren't the inhabitants of Vulcan pinned helpless to the surface, especially near where the hole was drilled?  *(In universe answers only please!)*

Below is the disaster unfolding:

Comment: Because gravity is inversely proportional to the square of the distance, so the red matter was able to collapse the core of the planet, which in turn sucked the rest of the planet.

Comment: @Gallifreian - I’m not sure that would explain it. The strength of the gravitational force exerted by an object does indeed depend on the inverse square of its distance, but if the micro black hole created by the red matter wasn’t increasing the gravity on the surface, its mass simply couldn’t have been significant relative to Vulcan. And I can’t imagine that its higher density would influence its gravitational effects overmuch (gravity of a spherical black hole, or the Earth itself, acts as if from a point source at the COM).

Comment: But given the sheer amount of gravity was sufficient to pull apart rock, the surface of the planet couldn't be so far away as to remain completely unaffected by the large gravity at its centre.  There seems to be _no_ impact on their ability to move on the planet's surface.

Comment: It is worth noting that the Earth does indeed have a very small, dense object at its center, and that doesn’t seem to cause too many problems....

Comment: @Adamant A black hole, _by definition_, has so much gravity that even light can't escape.  While the Earth's core is dense, it's nowhere near that level.

Comment: @JaneS - Of course, but I’m suggesting that having a dense object at the center of the planet wouldn’t necessarily create instability…but I need to look into this more.

Comment: No, I think it would create an instability. That part is realistic.

Comment: @Adamant One final thought - the Earth formed _around_ the dense core.  This one was injected into its centre billions of years later.  The difference is gravitational pull would easily cause the planet to become unstable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51982/discussion-between-adamant-and-jane-s).

Comment: Because while the script may have sucked massively, Vulcan didn't.

Comment: @Valorum I had a very legitimate reason for watching it again.  Chris Pine. :)

Comment: Excuse me, but did you want to say *Zachary Quinto and Anton Yelchin*? Must be autocorrect...

Comment: @Gallifreian Well, Karl Urban as well as Zachary Quinto and Anton Yelchin.  Oh, and don't forget Benedict Cumberbatch in _Into Darkness_!  Sigh :)

Comment: Yep, Benedict was the only reason I watched ST:ID. Too bad [this scene](https://youtu.be/7LXKjjS-eZI?t=1m31s) didn't make to the final cut though.

Comment: @Gallifreian LOL!  Love it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Surprisingly, a singularity the size of the droplet of red matter seen in the movie would *hardly* effect the surface gravity of Vulcan (that is, until it collapsed).

According to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26515/what-is-exactly-the-density-of-a-black-hole-and-how-can-it-be-calculated) answer on the Physics SE, a stellar black hole can be roughly calculated as being 6 * 10^18 kg/m^3. (As an aside, can we seriously get LaTeX enabled here?). The droplet of red matter we see in the movie is likely somewhere around 0.05 mL (based on a "standard" drop [according to pharmacists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop_(unit))). Putting this all together, we get a black hole of mass 3 * 10^11 kg.

That may seem like a large number, but it's actually not even on a planetary scale. The mass of Earth, for example, is 5.972 * 10^24 kg. I couldn't find data on the mass of Vulcan, but according to [Memory Alpha](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Vulcan_(planet)), with a surface gravity of 1.4 g, it is likely more massive than Earth (or at least on the same scale).

Therefore, when the singularity was originally released near Vulcan's core, **the inhabitants would have barely felt anything at all**. But as the <s>magically</s> stable  mini-singularity sucked in matter near the core, the planet would begin to collapse in on itself to fill the void from the core out to the mantle and then to the crust.

Comment: Would the singularity become more massive as it sucked in the planet, accelerating the process?

Comment: @DCShannon Yes. It will become approximately the mass of Vulcan.

Comment: Thanks!  A well considered answer that addresses my question :)